# Unit test OpenGL ES 2.0 interface

Tags: unit-testing, opengl-es-2.0

I'm implementing a OpenGL ES 2.0 interface/emulator, which allows access to a graphics system through 95% of the standard interface. Now, to check for bugs or other problems I'd like to have unit tests, which secure at least to some degree, that it is working like expected. Are there any unit tests available/known?

Comment: Well perhaps Piglit will help. Have yet to check it out. http://people.freedesktop.org/~nh/piglit/

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [OpenGL Conformance Testing](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/adopters/).

Comment: The problem is that I am doing my work for free, so the fees they want are not really an option.